# Standard way of combining data from multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am launching n threads to spread the workload of checking for and keeping track of collisions between particles in a simulation. I foolishly tried to create a global vector and `emplace_back` from multiple threads simultaneously the particle indices of colliding particles (from the particle array). This results it conflicts when threads try to write to the same vector. My current solution is that whenever I want to keep track of results from multiple threads, I need to define a new `std::vector<vector> myVectorSet(numberOfThreads)`, and then merge all of those vectors when the threads have all .join()ed.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Parallelism is partially violated when the results are return through a vector, since mutex will protect during read/write. Prefer returning a std::future from each thread independently and combining them at the end of computation.

Comment: I'm still new to mutex and havent even touched future. As long as my threads dont try to edit the same indices of the vector it should be fine right? I'm passing the iterator of the thread launching loop as the index of the vector to be worked with for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

What you’re looking for is a technique typically referred to as [Collision Islands](https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-iii-constrained-rigid-body-simulation) (see the optimizations section at the bottom of the page).

The idea here is data independence. By separating all simultaneous multi-body collisions into their own islands, you are able to parallelize the solver so that a thread handles each island by itself.

There’s so many different ways to handle it, though for my physics engine, I use a simple IslandInsert() function at the end of the Narrow Phase collision detection (when the collision was actually detected first). By using simple std::unordered_map, you can map your Collider pointers to an Island object, and using simple logic, build your islands as you detect collisions. 
Examples: [Physx-3.4](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/PhysX-3.4/blob/326e24039dd3f063afd211fad770e15bdd5ff4ea/PhysX_3.4/Source/LowLevel/software/include/PxsIslandManagerTypes.h) and [Bullet](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/61928fdde3b7910b280c79d995c356c6166c654e/src/BulletDynamics/Dynamics/btSimulationIslandManagerMt.cpp)

Here's a couple of snippets from my engine to demonstrate a possible implementation of the island building procedure

```
/* from the header, here are the containers used:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<struct Island>> Islands;
    std::unordered_map<class RigidBody*,std::shared_ptr<struct Island>> IslandLookup;
*/

void Solver::IslandInsert(Manifold& m)
{
    enum
    {
        NO_ISLANDS_NO_STATICS,
        A_HAS_ISLAND = 1,
        B_HAS_ISLAND = 1 << 1,
        A_STATIC = 1 << 2,
        B_STATIC = 1 << 3,
    };
    totalContactCount += m.cd.contactCount;
    ++manifoldCount;
    auto itA = IslandLookup.find(m.bodyA);
    auto itB = IslandLookup.find(m.bodyB);
    unsigned flag = 0;
    flag |= unsigned(itA != IslandLookup.end());
    flag |= unsigned(itB != IslandLookup.end()) << 1;
    flag |= unsigned(m.bodyA->physType == 0) << 2;
    flag |= unsigned(m.bodyB->physType == 0) << 3;
    switch(flag)
    {
    case NO_ISLANDS_NO_STATICS:    // no islands exist for this pair
        (IslandLookup[m.bodyB] = IslandLookup[m.bodyA] = NEW_ISLAND)->AddManifold(m);
        break;
    case A_STATIC:    // no islands exist and A is static
        (IslandLookup[m.bodyB] = NEW_ISLAND)->AddManifold(m);
        break;
    case B_STATIC:    //no islands exist and B is static
        (IslandLookup[m.bodyA] = NEW_ISLAND)->AddManifold(m);
        break;
    case A_STATIC | B_STATIC:    // both were static, so no islands should exist and this shouldn't even get here.
        throw "??";
        break;
    case A_HAS_ISLAND:    //only bodyA has an island and neither were static
        (IslandLookup[m.bodyB] = itA->second)->AddManifold(m);
        break;
    case A_HAS_ISLAND | B_STATIC:    //only bodyA has an island and B is static
        itA->second->AddManifold(m);
        break;
    case B_HAS_ISLAND:    //only bodyB has an island and neither were static
        (IslandLookup[m.bodyA] = itB->second)->AddManifold(m);
        break;
    case B_HAS_ISLAND | A_STATIC:    //only bodyB has an island and A is static
        itB->second->AddManifold(m);
        break;
    case A_HAS_ISLAND | B_HAS_ISLAND:    //both have an island, merge the two
        if(itA->second == itB->second)
        {
            itA->second->AddManifold(m);
        }
        else if(itA->second->bodyCount > itB->second->bodyCount)
        {
            itB->second->MergeInto(itA->second)->AddManifold(m);
            Util::VectorRemove(Islands, itB->second);
            IslandLookup[m.bodyB] = itA->second;
        }
        else
        {
            itA->second->MergeInto(itB->second)->AddManifold(m);
            Util::VectorRemove(Islands, itA->second);
            IslandLookup[m.bodyA] = itB->second;
        }
        break;
    case A_HAS_ISLAND | B_HAS_ISLAND | A_STATIC:    //both have an island, except A is static so A can't have an island...
        throw "??";
        break;
    case A_HAS_ISLAND | B_HAS_ISLAND | B_STATIC:    //both have an island, except B is static so B can't have an island...
        throw "??";
        break;
    case A_HAS_ISLAND | B_HAS_ISLAND | A_STATIC | B_STATIC:    //both have an island, except both are static and neither can have an island...
        throw "??";
        break;
    default: throw "??";
    }
}
// The following lines are methods used in the previous function

void Island::AddManifold(Manifold& m)
{
    bodies.emplace(m.bodyA, 0);
    bodies.emplace(m.bodyB, 0);
    manifolds.emplace_back(&m);
    bodyCount = unsigned(bodies.size());
    contactCount += m.cd.contactCount;
}

std::shared_ptr<Island> Island::MergeInto(std::shared_ptr<Island> other)
{
    for(Manifold* m : manifolds)
        other->AddManifold(*m);
    manifolds.clear();
    bodies.clear();
    contactCount = 0;
    bodyCount = 0;
    return other;
}
```

As an aside, there are two other trivially parallelizable sections of most traditional iterative solvers.

1. Collision Detection - Since typically there is only read-access during broad and narrow phase collision detection, you may parallelize the process by designating ranges of colliders to test per thread, or pairs of colliders for narrowphase. Insertion into containers will require a simple mutex and lock for that scope, but that’s two extra lines of code.
2. Collider updating - Assuming you have broadphase collision dection, the geometry typically will need to be update every frame (i.e. the axis aligned bounding boxes, or the bounding spheres). Depending on your implementation, this may require you to also update collider geometry as well. This process is also trivially parallelizable by designating ranges of colliders per thread to update.

Answer (score 0):

This sound like a classic readers/writers problem. You will need a lock (for mutual exclusion) and possibly a condition variable to manage the synchronization of accessing the global vector. Take a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readers-writers-problem-set-1-introduction-and-readers-preference-solution/) to get started:

Comment: This does seem like a solution, but it also looks like it would add way too much overhead for safety I don't really need.

Answer (score 0):

The parallel simulation of physics is an entire field on its own. In short, you need to find a way to partition your task into n similarly-sized jobs. Each job might me a subpart of the physical space, where you can run all of your simulation in isolation from the rest, then only cross-communicate between threads on the boundaries of the space.

Lets say that you are simulating a 2d box full of elastic projectiles. I might break up the box into a 4x4 grid and give each subspace to one thread to compute a single iteration of the simulation. Dealing with the projectiles that intersect the grid boundaries is a hard problem. You could have each thread resolve those particles on its North and West boundaries, but there are an unlimited supply of problems there; what do I do if particles 0, 1, and 2 and in contact. 0 is in one grid cell, 2 is in another, and 1 is on the boundary in between? In cases like this, you want to be able to hand around ownership of particles so all three of them are handled by one thread.

How? Well, that's why this is an entire field of its own. There's a lot of material out there. Can you be specific about the kind of sim you're doing? You may be better off grabbing something like The Open Dynamics Engine or similar open-source physical modeling tool.

Comment: Why have you created a problem to answer here that does not exist? You should assume that all other possible problems have been solved, and focus on the question being asked. I'm not ignorantly beginning something in which I need a general lesson on. I clearly stated my error, and a solution to it. I am just looking for alternate methods of gathering data from threads and recombining it. My problem is completely solved by creating a vector for each thread and then rejoining them at the end.